# Can't run executable that is in Path in Windows docker container

Tags: windows, powershell, docker, docker-for-windows

I am trying to run an executable from inside of a container from Power Shell and get an error message that it could not be found. However I've confirmed its directory is in Path and the executable is where I expect it to be. What am I missing?

```
PS C:\work\some_project> docker run -it --rm --name="iar_build" iar_env
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\docker_work> IarBuild.exe
IarBuild.exe : The term 'IarBuild.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ IarBuild.exe
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (IarBuild.exe:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS C:\docker_work> $Env:Path
C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\
OpenSSH\;C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files (x86)\IAR Systems\Embedded
 Workbench 8.1\common\bin"
PS C:\docker_work> ls 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IAR Systems\Embedded Workbench 8.1\common\bin\IarBuild.exe'


    Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\IAR Systems\Embedded Workbench 8.1\common\bin


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----         9/1/2018   4:09 AM         724992 IarBuild.exe


PS C:\docker_work>
```

My docker file contains the following:

```
...
# Add the IAR common\bin\ folder to the image's PATH
RUN setx path \
  "%path%;C:\Program Files (x86)\IAR Systems\Embedded Workbench 8.1\common\bin\"
...
CMD [ "powershell.exe", "-executionpolicy" , "Unrestricted" ]
```

Comment: `SETX` writes variables to the master environment in the registry `HKCU\Environment` and  do not affect the current CMD or PowerShell session (info from `setx /?`). Note that I don't know docker's `RUN setx path …`. The output from `$Env:Path` and consequent  `ls` seems to be a bit confusing because of trailing double quote in `$Env:Path`?

Comment: If I use cmd instead of powershell, e.g. `CMD [ "cmd" ]` I am able to call IarBuild.exe

Comment: What about `where.exe IarBuild.exe` from PowerShell?

Comment: ```PS C:\docker_work> where.exe IarBuild.exe
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).```

Comment: Is it a typo that trailing double quote in `$Env:Path`?

Comment: No, I was under the impression that whole string argument needed to be surrounded in quotes

Comment: I tried `setx /M PATH "%PATH%;C:\..."` and that did not work any differently. I tried all caps path and lowercase. But if I use /M other calls in my docker file fail.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to add a .\ so it will look like .\IarBuild.exe as it is currently trying to process the .exe as a cmdlet

Edit: If you start to type the name of the exe and press Tab it will autocomplete to .\IarBuild.exe if not type in manually

Hope that helps

Comment: `.\IarBuild.exe` has the same result. Tab autocompletion doesn't find it.

Comment: Sorry I have just read all your code since the .\IarBuild.exe isnt in the root folder Docker_Work it will not find it you will need to use Start-Process "C:\Program Files (x86)\IAR Systems\Embedded Workbench 8.1\common\bin\IarBuild.exe"

Comment: Powershell can find other utilities from directories in the `Path`, so why not this one?

Furthermore, this works exactly like I'd expect it on my host system. It just isn't working in the container.